# Is there an advantage to learning ESC- instead of ALT- beyond "maybe you'll use a system someday ..."?

Tags: keystrokes

I've been recently persuaded and coached to take the jump from vi to emacs. But one question sits funny. Why would one prefer to use the `ESC`- *sequence* for Meta- commands rather than ALT-key combinations. The symmetry is compelling (to me) toward the ALT- side. In particular using ALT-{digits} for C-u {digit} seems really nice. Do ESC-apists use that shortcut?

Now I'm a deep retro-computing enthusiast. Difference Engine, ENIAC, pdp/1, 7904. But realistically, I expect be running in an xterm for the forseeable future. Is there advantage to using ESC *in preference* to ALT as a habit-forming decision beyond the (seemingly remote) possibility of having to use an ALT-deficient setup sometime somewhere?

Comment: (1) Some terminals or other Emacs environments don't easily support a Meta key (e.g. Alt). (2) Some people find `ESC` sometimes handier, at least for some key sequences. (I use it for `C-x ESC ESC`, for instance, instead of `C-x M-ESC`.)

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but just a comment on a related issue:  I use the graphical version of Emacs and have configured the escape key to be a separate/independent modifier.  That is controlled by the `meta-prefix-char` -- I set it to `nil` when Emacs loads.  It needs to be changed to `nil` at the outset because some keymaps that load thereafter in my personal setup check to see the value of the `meta-prefix-char`.

Comment: For what it's worth, in 12 years with Emacs I don't recall ever using the ESC key

Answer (score 4):

Emacs has a *lot* of keybindings. I have never used a system where some Emacs keybindings did not clash with the underlying system. Every window manager intercepts a different set of keybindings, so the keystrokes don't even reach Emacs.

Using ESC is a fallback for when you can't type Alt-something directly in Emacs.